# Is it safe to set many Timeouts in JavaScript (NodeJS, ExpressJS)?

Tags: javascript, caching, settimeout

I've developed a Cache service with JavaScript (in NodeJS, via TypeScript) which one can set an "expiry" for an item (like Redis). to "expire" an item at desired time, "setTimeout" function is called for each cache item.

Implementation works like a charm, but a question arises:

Is it safe to call `setTimeout` for many times? or: How many Timeout references in "Event Loop" are safe?

```
import { DateManager } from 'path/to/utilities';

class CacheItem {
    private _timer: NodeJS.Timeout;
    expiry: Date;

    constructor(key: string, lifeTime: number) {
        this._timer = setTimeout(() => ChacheService.delete(key), lifeTime);
        this.expiry = DateManager.addMilliSecondsToNow(lifeTime);
    }

    remain() {
        return this.expiry.getTime() - DateManager.now().getTime();
    }

    clear() {
        clearTimeout(this._timer);
    }
}

export class ChacheService {
    private static _map = new Map<string, CacheItem>();

    static set(key: string, lifeTime: number) {
        return this._map.set(key, new CacheItem(key, lifeTime))
            .get(key);
    }

    static get(key: string) {
        return this._map.get(key);
    }

    static delete(key: string) {
        return this._map.delete(key);
    }
}
```

p.s.: my app isn't under heavy load, and `CacheService` is supposed to store at most 200 items per day, each has an expiry of 2 minutes.

Comment: Unless you're creating thousands of timeouts I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe as long as you don't overdo it. If you need to cache a lot of data you could add an [`'setInterval()'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function to your `'CacheService'` that iterates over the `'_map'` elements periodically. If an element is older than the expiration date, you can delete the corresponding key.

```
setInterval(() => {
  const value = this._map.get(key);
  
  if (value && value.expire <= new Date().getTime()) {
    this._map.delete(key);
    return null;
  }
  
  return value;
}, 3); // 3ms
```

You could also modify the `'get'` function and check the keys validity here. If a key has expired you delete it and return `'null'`. Here's an updated version of the `'get'` function:

```
static get(key) {
  const value = this._map.get(key);

  if (value && value.expire <= new Date().getTime()) {
    this._map.delete(key);
    return null;
  }

  return value;
}
```

By implementing these techniques, you can ensure that expired keys are properly handled in your caching system even if you need to handle more 200 items per day.

Comment: how i measure "overdo"? also, i read your answer in 2 ways: 1) keep timeouts and let them delete items automatically, but add an extra interval to ensure items are deleted , which i say is a redundant work actually. 2) remove timeouts and only set an interval to do the job, which is the EXACT thing i was avoiding. consider a Cache storing thuasands of items. get them one-by-one and do a logic on them is really a heavy job.

Comment: please note timeouts are cleared after a short priod of time, so crating many of them could not be a big problem (if they expire soon). but im not sure how BIG can it be!

Comment: Yeah using an interval might not be the ideal option when you want to store thousands of items. To answer your second question: It's hard to tell "how big it can be" since these will depend your the computer your application is running on.